# SSD TRIM Garbage Collection and affect on MFT Meta Data (security)

Tags: ssd, metadata, trim, mft

Does the way a SSD with trim and garbage collection handle deleted files make any changes to the deleted files MFT meta data entries for tiny files? What affect specifically do SSD's have on tiny files less than 1kb that are permanently resident in the MFT?

These are my findings from using conventional mechanical HDD:

I delete this folder and its sub dir and its file from root:
Music/Track/info.txt (400 bytes)

Then I run Recuva real quick and see the file is recoverable and try to erase it and get "file is resident in the MFT, delete failed" message.

I check the MFT and find the file is flagged but all data is still there. So I then have to wait for a new file to overwrite it which could take ages, or use a wiper tool to zero out the flagged MFT entries.

Does a SSD (trim enabled, GC) treat these small files any different? Does it attempt to zero out whats written in the text file so the MFT shows 0's or can't' it touch it because it is resident in the MFT just like with a conventional HDD?